# How to load .eml files as System.Net.Mail.MailMessage in UIPpath

Tags: email, attachment, eml, uipath

I have a bunch of .eml files inside a folder and I would like to know how can I load them inside UIPath in order to save their attachments.

One way I saw that this could be done is to add those mails inside a collection variable then use the save attachment function on that collection however I do not know how to load an .eml file inside a variable that is of type System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

Answer (score 0):

- Option 1: convert your EML files into `MailMessage` objects. To my knowledge, this can only be done by using third party tools, such as [MailBee.NET](http://%20https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/outlook-converter). You can then use the `InvokeCode` activity with your eml as an input parameter, and a MailMessage object as the output, which would then allow you to call the `SaveMailAttachments` activity (which expects a `MailMessage` object).
- Option 2: make use of UiPath's Desktop Automation capabilities. Having Outlook installed allows you to just double-click any eml file in order to open it. Then, just have your robot click on the [Save all Attachments](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-or-save-attachments-92f87f3f-1085-425a-87f6-08d43c19b43d#ID0EAABAAA=Office_2007) icon, followed by selecting a folder location. (Note that you can use just any client, e.g. Mozilla Thunderbird will work with eml files just as fine).

Comment: I will try using InvokeCode since i cannot use the desktop automation.
I have been asked not to use Outlook due to unexpected errors it could throw.

Comment: I only have InvokeVBA and that is only valid within Excel Application scope.
I have no InvokeCode method available

Comment: InvokeCode requires at least v2017.1: https://activities.uipath.com/docs/invoke-code. Still, isn't the whole point of UiPath not having to write any code at all? Not using Outlook because of the potential issues isn't the best argument, as the whole process of extracting attachments from emails via code could fail was well. So, you'd need at least some error handling in both cases. Re Desktop Automation, keep in mind that Outlook isn't your only option for reading emls.